# Group By json data

Tags: javascript, json, group-by

I'm very new with coding javascript and also with json data.

I have this code and first of all i want to Group by "week" but i only want to sum the column "resultat"

The column "Start" do i want to show the first value, and in the column "Slut" i want to show the latest value.

Is this possible? And if, do anyone have any suggestions how?

As i sad i'm really new so i'm totaly lost :)

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "/weekresult.json", false);
request.overrideMimeType("application/json");
request.send(null);

var jsonData, i, j, x = "";


var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(jsonData);

  x += "<table style='border:1px SOLID black;'>";
  x += "<tr><th style='background:silver;'>Vecka</th><th style='background:silver;'>Öppning</th><th style='background:silver;'>Stängning</th><th style='background:silver;'>Resultat</th><th style='background:silver;'>Procent</th></tr>";

for (i in jsonData.vecka) {
  x += "<tr>";
  x += "<td style='text-align:center;width:20%;'>" + jsonData.vecka[i].week + "</td>";
  x += "<td style='text-align:center;width:20%;'>" + jsonData.vecka[i].start + " SEK</td>";
  x += "<td style='text-align:center;width:20%;'>" + jsonData.vecka[i].slut + " SEK</td>";
  x += "<td style='text-align:center;width:20%;'>" + jsonData.vecka[i].resultat + " SEK</td>";
  x += "<td style='text-align:center;width:20%;'>" + jsonData.vecka[i].procent + "%</td>";
  x += "</tr>";
}
  x += "</table>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;



</script>``
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample of what the jsonData in response looks like. It is hard to get behind what you mean by "grouping by week" and "sum the column resultat" as we don't know what the data looks like.

Comment: This i the json file


{"vecka":[{"week":"20-15","start":1000,"slut":1019,"resultat":"19","procent":"1.90"},{"week":"20-15","start":1019,"slut":1036,"resultat":"17","procent":"1.67"},{"week":"20-15","start":1036,"slut":1060,"resultat":"24","procent":"2.32"},{"week":"20-15","start":1060,"slut":1090,"resultat":"30","procent":"2.83"},{"week":"20-16","start":1090,"slut":1121,"resultat":"31","procent":"2.84"}]}

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that does what you are looking for. It does not generate any DOM Elements, however it takes care of all the logic except for "percent" as you did not specify what is supposed to happen to that value.

To summarize:

1. Create an Array that holds all the "groups"
2. Fill that Array with the grouped weeks. If a week is already tracked, add its value to the tracking objects `data`-Array, else create a new Group.
3. Now just iterate through every group, display the groups `week` value and perform the logic to finding the min (start), max (slut) and summed (resultat) values. All of that can be done with the `reduce` method.
4. Log/Display the results.

```
const { vecka } = { "vecka": [{ "week": "20-15", "start": 1000, "slut": 1019, "resultat": "19", "procent": "1.90" }, { "week": "20-15", "start": 1019, "slut": 1036, "resultat": "17", "procent": "1.67" }, { "week": "20-15", "start": 1036, "slut": 1060, "resultat": "24", "procent": "2.32" }, { "week": "20-15", "start": 1060, "slut": 1090, "resultat": "30", "procent": "2.83" }, { "week": "20-16", "start": 1090, "slut": 1121, "resultat": "31", "procent": "2.84" }] };

const sets = [];

for (let set of vecka) {
    // Find week if it is already tracked
    const trackedWeek = sets.filter(w => w.time == set.week)[0];

    if (!trackedWeek) {
        // If week is not already being tracked, create a new entry
        sets.push({ time: set.week, data: [set]});
    } else {
        // If week is already being tracked, add data to week
        trackedWeek.data.push(set);
    }
};

for (let set of sets) {
    // Find start
    const start = set.data.reduce((min, { start }) => {
        if (!min) return start;

        return min > start ? start : min;
    }, null);

    // Find end
    const end = set.data.reduce((max, { slut }) => {
        if (!max) return slut;

        return max < slut ? slut : max;
    }, null);

    // Accumulate resultat
    const resultat = set.data.reduce((acc, { resultat }) => (acc += parseInt(resultat)), 0);

    console.log("week: ", set.time);
    console.log("start: ", start);
    console.log("slut: ", end);
    console.log("resultat: ", resultat);
}
```

Hope this helps. Take a look at Arrays and Objects and their methods. That is usually all you need to perform these kinds of manipulations.

Comment: I saw now that for "start" and "slut" column do you use in and max. What i want is the first and the last value. In this example it's being right with min and max but in other case is dosen't.

Is it possible to get the first and last value?

Comment: You need to replace the start/end function expressions reduce statement with an Array.map for `start`and `slut` and then just select the first (start) and last (slut) element as the output.

Comment: I'm really bad at this type of coding så mutch ask how? Searched after examples that can pass into my code. But no look.